# Run a method on tab switch or when leaving a UIViewController's focus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to run a method when a user switches to another tab or when the application is closed. Is there a way to do this with the iphone sdk?

I've tried looking at the methods for the view controllers and the tab bars, but I didn't see any methods that seemed to do this.

I've also tried doing this with "Editing Did End" methods, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a method when a tab is tapped (and I'm assuming you're referring to a standard UITabBar), just implement `tabBar:didSelectItem:` in your tabBar's delegate.

To run code when your application quits, implement `applicationWillTerminate:` in your app's delegate.

Comment: I've googled for all of this stuff. Is there a book or some online documentation that you use to find these methods?